# How to validate entity with associaction?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I have **form class**:

```
...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', TextType::class); 
    $builder->add('surname', TextType::class);
    $builder->add('address', IntegerType::class); // write custom field type?
}
...
```

I use it to validate **Customer** entity, where $address field is association:

```
...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address")
 * @Assert\CustomAddress // write this custom validation constraint?
 */
private $address;
...
```

Now how to validate $address value? Now I get (what didn't surprise me):

> Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Address", "string" given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make a form for your Address Entity, something like:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Address;
// ...

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('address1', TextType::class); 
        $builder->add('city', TextType::class);
        // ...
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Address::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then update your `CustomerType` to use that class, something like:

```
use AppBundle\Form\Type\AddressType;

// ...

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', TextType::class); 
    $builder->add('surname', TextType::class);
    $builder->add('address', AddressType::class);
}
```

Then your Address entity should be validated automatically without needing a custom validation constraint.

Comment: Okey works. So now I need write transformer to convert from int to address entity? Or fetch it before $fomr->submit(...)? I'm right?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything like that - your association is being treating as a full entity, not a traditional foreign key integer.  So you shouldn't need a data transformer at all.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for answer. You are right. Anyway I ended up with exception:"Compound forms expect an array or NULL on submission". I give up for now, I will try fix this tomorrow.

Comment: I've never seen that error :) let me know if you need more help